# Can I use USA IP without VPN or Proxy?

Tags: internet, proxy, ip

Can I use USA IP without VPN or Proxy? I'm overseas now and I need to use my back home IP, but i don't wanna use any VPN or Proxy stuffs?
Anyone got an idea about how to link my IP from back home to my computer here? I know this is a stupid question but I just want to know how I can use a USA IP from another country without VPN or other proxy stuffs.
Helps!
Thanks in advance.`

Comment: Why can;t you use VPN? You;re pretty much going to need to.

Answer (score 2):

No. You could only use your home IP if you had setup a proxy or VPN on your home PC, other than that a public VPN/Proxy will let you use A US IP.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to use your home IP? It might be easier to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

If you had set up your home computer as a server, you could've tunneled through it to get your home IP. Example link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the answer you're looking for, but if you still have on your home in the U.S. a computer turned on and connected to the Internet, you could use software such as TeamViewer or RDP to connect from your current location to the computer in the U.S.